# VBA clicking buttons in loop

Tags: vba, selenium-webdriver

I'm using VBA + Selenium to export data.

Work sequence is as below

1. enter specific numbers input box
2. Click button

   `Sel.FindElementByXPath("//tbody/tr[2]/td[6]/button[1]/em[1]").Click`
3. Export data

Above works should be in loop until the end.

Problem is that sometimes number of click buttons can be different.

How can i make VBA to click the button until the end?

FYI, I found the rule that "tr[2]" changes like first one is tr[2] and second one is tr[3].

```
//tbody/tr[2]/td[6]/button[1]/em[1]
```

Comment: `Sel.FindElementByXPath("//tbody/tr[" & (n+1) & "]/td[6]/button[1]/em[1]").Click` where `n` is your loop counter

Comment: Is there HTML or a website? And your loop? The danger with clicks are they often to lead to page changes that can render prior xpaths obsolete.